# How to get string '###' work in velocity

Tags: escaping, velocity

thanks for reading.

I am using springmvc + velocity to build my application.
And in the view page xxx.vm, I want to put some code like this:

`<a class="action-btn" href="###">action</a>`
(For `"###"` is more compatible than `"javascript:void(0);"` in all browsers.)

We have known that the `##` in velocity is working as commending command like `//` in java. So that code will become `<a class="action-btn" href="` when it works.

So is there any escaping method to the character `#` ? (I have tried `\#` and `/#`, and they did not work for me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
#set($h = '#')
<a class="action-btn" href="$h$h$h">action</a>
```

This said, if you are using Velocity-Tools, you can also use the escape tool:

```
<a class="action-btn" href="$esc.h$esc.h$esc.h">action</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#[[###]]#
```

This escapes the text in the middle. It's a good solution for large sections.

```
#[[
#foreach ($woogie in $boogie)
 nothing will happen to $woogie
#end
]]#
```

Source: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences